# How to check whether the image from the specified URL loaded or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Through an ajax call, I am procuring URLs which I need to use to change the `src` of an `img`. However this is taking time. Meanwhile i need to show loading or something. How do i check whether `$("#img#).attr("src","http:\\fsomething ");` has loaded the image on the page or not?

Comment: Can you show your code for the AJAX call? My advice would be to add the loading image before the AJAX call, and then add an AJAX callback on Success to remove the loading image.

Comment: @Spokey I might agree except that question and none of the answers are using jQuery, which has pretty good support for callbacks in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the call to show the Loading image before the AJAX Call:

```
$('#ajaxLoadingContainer').html('<img src="secure_content/images/ajax-loader-small.gif">');

$.ajax({
    url: 'secure/ajax.php?action=checkSession',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'HTML',
    async: true,
    success: removeAjaxLoader,
});

function removeAjaxLoader() {
    $('#ajaxLoadingContainer').html('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get a callback event, after the new image is loaded

```
var isrc = "http:\\fsomething ";
var image = new Image();
    image.onload=function(){
       //Image load callback
    }
image.src = isrc;
$('body').append(image);
```

Use this code in the ajax success function. Show a loading image before the ajax call and hide the loading image in the image load callback function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://stackoverflow.com/secure_content/images/ajax-loader-small.gif',
type:'HEAD',
error: function()
{
    //file not exists
},
success: function()
{
    //file exists
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript Image() for this.

`var img = new Image();
   // Show loading image here
   jQuery('#loadingImg').show(); 
   img.onload = function(){
       // image  has been loaded 
       // Hide the loading image 
      jQuery('#loadingImg').hide();
   };
   img.src = 'image_url';`